# Firewalld is not working,. port open but I can't reach from other server

Tags: linux, redhat, firewalld

I got a wildfly 9 server on REHEL 7 with ports http=4070. Then I executed the following instructions:

```
[root@linux]# firewall-cmd --add-port=4070/tcp --permanent
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 4070:tcp
success
[root@linux]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
    target: default
    icmp-block-inversion: no
    interfaces: eth1
    sources:
    services: dhcpv6-client ssh
    ports:  4070/tcp
    protocols:
    masquerade: no
    forward-ports:
    sourceports:
    icmp-blocks:
    rich rules:

[root@linux]# getenforce
Disabled
```

I'm not using iptables.

I can get the output from wget http://localhost:4070 from linux server itlself. Even though, I can't reach from other server or PC. What can I do for this case?

Added 1:

```
ss -tnlp | grep :4070
```

Output:

```
LISTEN     0      128          *:4070                     *:*
```

Added 2:

```
journalctl -u firewalld | grep "4070"
```

Output: Empty, no results.

Comment: Please show the output of `ss -tnlp | grep :4070`. Also always provide the actual error message you encounter.

Comment: Ok I added the output in the content of the post

Comment: Have you checked the logs? `sudo journalctl -u firewalld | grep "4070"`

Comment: I made the second added. What I did was restarting the server and then the web server was loaded and it started to work.

Comment: That confirms what Ace wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: Why do I have to reload it if the message shows: 'Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 4070:tcp'?

Comment: `--permanent` make rule be written on disk. With `--permanent` rule is not applied immediately. ALREAD_ENABLED means you already have this in saved configuration. You have to `--reload`  to apply saved configuration or try the same without `--permanent`.

Comment: To apply any changes made to the firewall configuration. Just to make sure that the whole configuration is being applied.